# Imagebutton clickable area is bigger than the image

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, imagebutton

I have multiple imagebutton shaped like a trapezoid, but the clickable area is a transparent square all around them (bigger than the image).  I want only the trapezoid to be clickable because the trapezoids overlaps because the square shape. Thank u!

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnAgua"
    android:layout_width="93dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/agua"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />
```

Screenshot of my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM4IN.png

Comment: share a screenshot of yor page

Comment: done with the screenshot!

Comment: give elevation to trapezoid.

Comment: android:elevation="5dp"